# OUTER APPLY table to itself multiple times - can CASE be used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it necessary to `OUTER APPLY` multiple times in the following query, or could I get the same result by somehow using 1 `APPLY` with some included `CASE` statements?

(p.s. I realise `FIRST_VALUE` is an alternative but I'm interested in the use of `APPLY`)

```
SELECT  
  Name,
  AgeCat,
  Country,
  X.DateKey,
  WagerAmt    = SUM(Revenue),
  FirstNAC    = z.DateKey,    
  FirstNA     = j.DateKey,
  FirstN      = q.DateKey  
FROM    #x X
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
            FROM    #x Y
            WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name AND
                    X.AgeCat = Y.AgeCat AND
                    x.Country = y.Country 
            ORDER BY DateKey
            ) z
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
            FROM    #x Y
            WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name AND
                    X.AgeCat = Y.AgeCat
            ORDER BY DateKey
            ) j
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
            FROM    #x Y
            WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name
            ORDER BY DateKey
            ) q
GROUP BY  
    Name,
    AgeCat,
    Country,
    X.DateKey
    z.DateKey,    
    j.DateKey,
    q.DateKey;
```

Comment: Please provide a working SQL Fiddle. `Column 'z.DateKey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
`

Comment: @MartinSmith - my mistake: will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this can be done with a case. A sub-select of some type will be necessary.

EDIT:
As JOINs the query would look like this:

```
SELECT  
  Name,
  AgeCat,
  Country,
  X.DateKey,
  WagerAmt    = SUM(Revenue),
  FirstNAC    = z.DateKey,    
  FirstNA     = j.DateKey,
  FirstN      = q.DateKey  
FROM    #x X
inner join
(
    SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
    FROM    #x Y
    WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name AND
            X.AgeCat = Y.AgeCat AND
            x.Country = y.Country 
    ORDER BY DateKey
) z
inner join 
(
    SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
    FROM    #x Y
    WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name AND
            X.AgeCat = Y.AgeCat
    ORDER BY DateKey
) j
inner join (
    SELECT  TOP(1) DateKey 
    FROM    #x Y
    WHERE   X.Name = Y.Name
    ORDER BY DateKey
) q
GROUP BY  
    Name,
    AgeCat,
    Country,
    X.DateKey,
    z.DateKey,
    j.DateKey,
    q.DateKey;
```

Note that the GROUP BY has changed as well: since APPLY returns 1 row only, and theoretically these sub-selects could return multiples, their fields need to be in the GROUP too.

Comment: ok - my thinking about CASE was just a hunch - what does the syntax using a sub-select look like?